# How to get the active class value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have three links (anchor tag) that represent standards like std1, std2. I want to get the active class value.

```
                                       <li data-interest="1" class="check <? if($std_id == 1){?> class="active"<?}?>" >
                                            <a href="#1" onclick="changeDiv('1','S1')" data-toggle="tab" title="S1">
                                                <span class="round-tabs green">
                                                    <span class="grade_catgory">S1</span>
                                                </span> 
                                            </a></li>
                                        <li data-interest="2" class="check <? if($std_id == 2){?> class="active"<?}?>" >
                                            <a  onclick="changeDiv('2','S2')" data-toggle="tab" title="S2">
                                                <span class="round-tabs yellow">
                                                    <span class="grade_catgory">S2</span>
                                                </span> 
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
```

**jQuery**

```
      $(function() {
     // var val = $('ul#myTab1').find('li.active').data('interest');
     var itemType = $('ul#myTab1').find('li.check').data('interest');
      alert(itemType);
    });
```

I want the value like 1, 2, etc. Where can I put this?

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: use .`attr('data-interest')` instead of `.data()` i assume you are not getting the value of that attr

Comment: Use this: `<li data-interest="1" class="check <? if($std_id == 1){?> active<?}?> ">`

Comment: This question appears to have been abandoned, with one answer indicated as not the solution, and another replied to. I wonder if it would be worth putting this on hold as "unclear"? In the unlikely event that you still wish to receive an answer, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li").each(function(){ // loop through all li
  if($(this).hasClass("active")) { // check if li has active class
    console.log($(this).data("interest")) // get the value of data-interest attribute
  }
})
```

Comment: almost right..But looping cause others are undefine.I want only r=the selected one

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var val = $('body').find('li.active').attr('data-interest');
```